# How can I setState in new Reactjs function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying out the new react for functions without class and i'm trying to use setstate but it's not working, saying undefined if i used it straight or saying it's not a function if i remove `this.` from it.

here is my code

```
    import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  var [sum1, setSum1] = useState(0);
  var [sum2, setSum2] = useState(0);

  function handleClick(props) {
    let buttonText = props.target.value;
    let inputText = document.getElementById('result').value;
    console.log(inputText + buttonText);
    // let sum1 =setState;
    // let sum2 =setState;
    
    
      let  total = inputText + buttonText;
        if (total.charAt(0) === "0") {
          
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").value = total;
        }
        if (props.target.value === "clear") {
          document.getElementById("result").value = "";
        }
        if (props.target.value === "+") {
          sum1 =document.getElementById("result").value.slice(0, -1);
          setSum1({sum1:parseFloat(sum1)});
          // alert(sum1);
          document.getElementById("result").value = "";
          alert(sum1);
        }
        if (props.target.value === "=") {
          
            sum2 =document.getElementById("result").value.slice(0, -1);
            setSum2({sum2:parseFloat(sum2)});
            alert(sum1+sum2);
            document.getElementById("result").innerText = sum1+sum2;
          }
        return total;
  }
    
    
  
  // function handleClick2(props) {
  //   document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = eval(document.getElementById("result").value);
  // }
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <div id="ans" className="answer">Ans = 0</div>
          <input type="text" onChange={handleClick} readOnly  placeholder="0" className="inputid" id="result"/>
           <hr/> 
           {/* calculator buttons below */}
           {/* button + */}
           <button className="opbut" value="+" onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
           {/* button - */}
           <button className="opbut" value="-" onClick={handleClick}>-</button>
           {/* button × */}
           <button className="opbut" value="*" onClick={handleClick}>×</button>
           {/* button ÷ */}
           <button className="opbut"  value="/" onClick={handleClick}>÷</button>
           {/* button 0 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={0} onClick={handleClick}>0</button>
           {/* button 1 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={1} onClick={handleClick}>1</button>
           {/* button 2 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={2}  onClick={handleClick}>2</button>
           {/* button 3 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={3} onClick={handleClick}>3</button>
           {/* button 4 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={4} onClick={handleClick}>4</button>
           {/* button 5 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={5} onClick={handleClick}>5</button>
           {/* button 6 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={6} onClick={handleClick}>6</button>
           {/* button 7 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={7} onClick={handleClick}>7</button>
           {/* button 8 */}
           <button className="calbut" value={8} onClick={handleClick}>8</button>
           {/* button 9 */}
           <button className="calbut"  value={9} onClick={handleClick}>9</button>
           {/* button ( */}
           <button className="opbut"  value="clear" onClick={handleClick}>C</button>
           {/* button ) */}
           <button className="opbut" value="Del" onClick={handleClick}>Del</button>
           {/* button % */}
           <button className="opbut" value="%" onClick={handleClick}>%</button>
           {/* button y^ */}
           <button className="opbut" value="^" onClick={handleClick}>y^</button>
           {/* button total = */}
           <button className="ansbut" value="=" onClick={handleClick}>=</button>
           <hr/>
           <div className="appName">A Simple React Calculator - Jayflo</div>
        </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

above is the code....
as i'm trying to select a button, and onclick operator selected, setstate and delete textfield then accept another input and operate both input...

Comment: You shouldn't be using native JS element methods with React as React has it's own way of updating the DOM. You should familiarise yourself with [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html). Also, functional components don't have a `render` method.

Comment: Provide the complete code

Comment: Also, `setState` doesn't exist as you haven't defined it using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: return rather...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has its own particular way of updating the DOM based on the state of (value of) the elements, so you can't use native element methods.

In this example we use three [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html): `useState`, `useEffect`, and `useRef`.

`useState` maintains the state of the input element, the updated calculation, and the final evaluation which is passed into the result div.

`useEffect` ensures that after the result has been completed we clear the `calc` state.

`useRef` is React's way of identifying an element. In this case, after each button is clicked, the input element is focused on again.

Here's a working example based on your code.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');
  const [ calc, setCalc ] = useState('');
  const [ result, setResult ] = useState('');
  
  const inputRef = useRef();

  // Update the input state when the value is changed
  function handleInput(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setInput(value);
  }

  // When the input is no longer focused (we've clicked
  // a button) update the `calc` state
  function handleBlur(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setCalc(prev => prev + value);
  }

  // When we click a button, either update the `calc` state,
  // or if we click "=", update the `result` state
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { nodeName, value } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
      setInput('');
      inputRef.current.focus();
      switch(value) {
        case '=': {
          setResult(eval(calc));
          break;
        }
        case 'clear': {
          setCalc('');
          break;
        }
        default: {
          setCalc(prev => prev + value);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // When the result is updated, clear the `calc` state
  useEffect(() => setCalc(''), [result]);

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <div>{`Result: ${result}`}</div>
        <div>{`Calc: ${calc}`}</div>
        <input autoFocus ref={inputRef} onBlur={handleBlur} onChange={handleInput} type="text" value={input} />
        </div>
      <div class="buttons" onClick={handleClick}>
       <button value="+">+</button>
       <button value="-">-</button>
       <button value="*">×</button>
       <button value="/">÷</button>
       <button value="0">0</button>
       <button value="1">1</button>
       <button value="2" >2</button>
       <button value="3">3</button>
       <button value="4">4</button>
       <button value="5">5</button>
       <button value="6">6</button>
       <button value="7">7</button>
       <button value="8">8</button>
       <button value="9">9</button>
       <button value="clear">C</button>
       <button value="Del">Del</button>
       <button value="%">%</button>
       <button value="^">y^</button>
       <button value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.container { display: flex; width: 200px; height: 200px; }

.buttons {
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Alternative method which reduces the number of states and doesn't have to use `useRef` because now there's no input.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ calc, setCalc ] = useState('');
  const [ result, setResult ] = useState('');
  
  // When we click a button, either update the `calc` state,
  // or if we click "=", update the `result` state
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { nodeName, value } = e.target;
    if (nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
      switch(value) {
        case '=': {
          setResult(eval(calc));
          break;
        }
        case 'clear': {
          setCalc('');
          break;
        }
        default: {
          setCalc(prev => prev + value);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // When the result is updated, clear the `calc` state
  useEffect(() => setCalc(''), [result]);

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <div class="results">
        <div>{`Result: ${result}`}</div>
        <br />
        <div>{`Calc: ${calc}`}</div>
        </div>
      <div class="buttons" onClick={handleClick}>
       <button value="+">+</button>
       <button value="-">-</button>
       <button value="*">×</button>
       <button value="/">÷</button>
       <button value="0">0</button>
       <button value="1">1</button>
       <button value="2" >2</button>
       <button value="3">3</button>
       <button value="4">4</button>
       <button value="5">5</button>
       <button value="6">6</button>
       <button value="7">7</button>
       <button value="8">8</button>
       <button value="9">9</button>
       <button value="clear">C</button>
       <button value="Del">Del</button>
       <button value="%">%</button>
       <button value="^">y^</button>
       <button value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.container { display: flex; }

.results { width: 40px; }

.buttons {
  margin-left: 6em;
  padding: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #111;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: @MiraBeeCalifonia. No problem. It takes a little time to understand how React works, but you'll get there. But the concept is pretty simple. Update the state, the component re-renders, and the new state gets reflected in the JSX.

Comment: @MiraBeeCalifonia. There was an easier way to do this reducing the number of states, and getting rid of the input. Just tap out the numbers on the calculator instead. I've updated my answer with a second example.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED: About your Calculator**

What you're showing is mixing react and HTML and Vanilla JS. It's not well seen and it's harder to maintain. So, the react approach is available in this new code sandbox:

(It's only handling the Sum, as an example purpose of how we can do this application using only react)

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-star-hf90r

**About USE STATE**

You can see one example working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-cori-5xi34?file=/src/App.js:50-759

The easiest way to do this is using hooks. Now, there are multiple hooks. In your case, you will need `React.useState`, it'll return 2 things: the value, the setter.

```js
const [myValue, mySetter] = React.useState(defaultValue);
```

After that, everything will work almost the same, in this case, I've defined 3 states (sum1, sum2, and result) and 2 extra functions, handleResult and handleClear, which I could guess from your code.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [sum1, setSum1] = React.useState(0);
  const [sum2, setSum2] = React.useState(0);
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState(sum1 + sum2);

  const handleCalculate = () => {
    setResult(+sum1 + +sum2);
  }

  const handleClear = () => {
    setResult(0);
    setSum1(0);
    setSum2(0);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      Sum1: <input type="number" onChange={e => setSum1(e.target.value)} value={sum1}/> <br/>
      Sum2: <input type="number" onChange={e => setSum2(e.target.value)} value={sum2}/> <br/>
      <button onClick={handleCalculate}>Calculate</button>
      <button onClick={handleClear}>Clear</button>
      <h2>Result: {result}</h2>
      <h3>Interactive: {+sum1 + +sum2}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's some information on how to create a working React snippet [over on meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: I've seen them but I didn't know all the power and how to use them! Thanks so much @Andy

Comment: [Here's the example I use](https://pastebin.com/AjqD1CWj). I just paste that into the answer, and update the `Example` code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to keep track of a pending state

To make use of useState, first you have to import it

```
import { useState } from "react";
```

Then,

```
const [ isPending , setIsPending ] = useState(false);
```

the value you pass to the `useState(initialValue)` function will be the initial value of the state.
You can pass any value like `array` `string` or `object` to the `useState()` function

To set/change the value of the state you declared

```
setIsPending(true);
```

The value of your state is held by the `isPending` variable

Answer (score 0):

```
function App() {
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("InitialValue");
const [sum1, setSum1] = useState(0);
const [sum2, setSum2] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = (props) =>{
    setButtonText(props.target.value)
    let inputText = document.getElementById('result').value;
    console.log(inputText + buttonText);
    
      let  total = inputText + buttonText;
        if (total.charAt(0) === "0") {
          
        } else {
          document.getElementById("result").value = total;
        }
        if (props.target.value === "clear") {
          document.getElementById("result").value = "";
        }
        if (props.target.value === "+") {
          setSum1(parseFloat(document.getElementById("result").value));
          // alert(sum1);
          document.getElementById("result").value = "";
          
        }
        if (props.target.value === "=") {
          
            alert(sum1);
          setSum2(parseFloat(document.getElementById("result").value))
            
            document.getElementById("result").innerText = sum1+sum2;
          }
        return total;
  }
    return(
///my code
)
```

please try this now.

Comment: if it does not work then send me your whole code I will fix it

Comment: As a React developer you should give your answer a little more thought because that's not how React works.